# Gibbons-Hawking space is resolution of $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_k$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I have a question regarding the Gibbons-Hawking construction of Hyperkahler fourfolds. Let ${a_i}\in\mathbb{R}^3, i =1,\dots,k$ be collinear points and construct a Hyperkahler manifold by starting with a circle bundle over $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{a_i\}$ and applying the Gibbons-Hawking ansatz. Call the resulting manifold $X$. In a lot of sources I have read it is asserted that $X$ (with a suitable choice of complex structure) is in fact biholomorphic to the minimal resolution of $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_k$. They usually state that this is shown by plumbing the $(-2)$-curves in a particular way. However, I am not familiar with this argument nor was I able to find any source explaining it thoroughly.

For any further details please see these [notes by Andrew Nietzke](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/neitzke/teaching/392C-higgs-bundles/higgs-bundles.pdf). In particular, I am interested in the exercise 3.16 (special case of the above question for $k=2$ and $X$ is supposed to be biholomorphic to the cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^1$) as well as example 3.15.

Any pointer or reference would be very helpful. Thanks.